# dm_exec_query_stats returning all NULLs for Worker and Elapsed time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, dmv

I am executing the following statement on a customer's SQL Server. The version is Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-GDR) (KB5021129) .

```
declare @Milliseconds int


SELECT  top 200  * 
--sum([Total Worker Time])  
FROM
(
-- Get top total worker time queries for entire instance (Query 36) (Top Worker Time Queries)
SELECT DB_NAME(t.[dbid])                AS [Database Name],
SUBSTRING(t.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(t.TEXT)
ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1)  AS Command,
qs.execution_count AS [Execution Count],
qs.total_worker_time / @Milliseconds    AS [Total Worker Time], 
qs.min_worker_time/@Milliseconds        AS [Min Worker Time],
qs.total_worker_time/qs.execution_count / @Milliseconds  AS [Avg Worker Time], 
qs.max_worker_time / @Milliseconds      AS [Max Worker Time], 
qs.last_worker_time  / @Milliseconds    AS [Last Worker Time], 
qs.min_elapsed_time / @Milliseconds     AS [Min Elapsed Time], 
qs.total_elapsed_time  / @Milliseconds  AS [Total Elapsed Time], 
qs.total_elapsed_time/qs.execution_count / @Milliseconds  AS [Avg Elapsed Time], 
qs.max_elapsed_time  / @Milliseconds    AS [Max Elapsed Time],
qs.last_elapsed_time  / @Milliseconds   AS [Last Elapsed Time],
qs.min_logical_reads                    AS [Min Logical Reads],
qs.total_logical_reads/qs.execution_count AS [Avg Logical Reads],
qs.max_logical_reads                    AS [Max Logical Reads], 
qs.creation_time                        AS [Creation Time],
qs.last_execution_time,
t.[text]                                AS [Query Text]
--, qp.query_plan AS [Query Plan] -- uncomment out these columns if not copying results to Excel
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats            AS qs WITH (NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) AS t 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) AS qp 
)
AS T
order by [Avg Worker Time]  desc
```

There are values in  the `[Command]`, `[Execution Count]` and the `[Query Text]` output columns. And there are values in the `[Min Logical Reads]` and `[Max Logical Reads]` output columns too.

But  the value of the `[... Worker ...]` or `[... Elapsed Time]` columns are all `NULL` in every row.

#### Question

Is there an explanation for why these values are all `NULL`?

I have been executing this query on other customer sites with great success. I got this query off the web and thankful for the soul who wrote it.

Comment: Milliseconds isn't set anywhere, it's null, dividing by the null returns null.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Thank you so much. I must have accidentally gotten rid of the set to 1000 when running on the server. But I had gotten habituated to running this query and returning results that I did not realize that i had gotten rid of the assignment

Answer (score 1):

Answer From Sean Gallardy :
Milliseconds isn't set anywhere, it's null, dividing by the null returns null. –